# How does the Populist badge work?

Tags: support, badges

Taken from this [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/96413/ive-lost-my-portal-from-the-end-to-the-over-world/96416#96416):

> Highest scoring answer that outscored an accepted answer with score of
>   more than 10 by more than 2x

So the answer accepted was  a score of -11.  My answer was +11.  This is more than 10, and more than 2x the answer accepted score's answer.

Why haven't I received the populist badge?

Comment: -11 * 2 = -22, just saying.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You misread the requirements.

- *The accepted answer* must have a score of at least then 10.
- *Your answer* must have more than twice the score of the accepted answer.

Yeah. It's a gold badge for a reason. (See also: [Reversal](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/badges/95/reversal).)

Comment: Woops. Must have misread it.  My bad.